# Как сделать активную кнопку при выборе размера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как удалить `disabled` из ссылки `a` после выбора любого размера?

```js
$('#size').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.checkallow').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.checkallow').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" tabindex="-1">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Не выбрано</option>
  <option value="38-XXS">38-XXS</option>
  <option value="40-XS">40-XS</option>
</select>

<a class="checkallow" href="#" disabled="">В корзину</a>
```

Comment: Где элемент с классом `.checkallow`, где элемент `<size>` и зачем элементу `<a>` бесполезный для него атрибут/свойство  `disabled`?

Comment: Почему `disabled` бесполезный? Он на сайте работает., Можно и `button` использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С элементами разобрались, а по поводу "*Он на сайте работает*" - тут бы хорошо понять, что вы под этой фразой подразумеваете. Если вы предполагаете, что `disabled` предотвращает переход по ссылке, то вы ошибаетесь. Перехода нет по причине вот этого маленького кусочка кода: `href="#"`. Единственное логичное объяснение - это то, что вы используете атрибут в качестве селектора, но от этого атрибут не становиться более полезным. Например:

```js
const checkallow = $('.checkallow');
$('#size').on('change', function() {
  checkallow.attr('disabled', $(this).val() === '');
});
```

```css
a[disabled] {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" tabindex="-1">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Не выбрано</option>
  <option value="38-XXS">38-XXS</option>
  <option value="40-XS">40-XS</option>
</select>

<a class="checkallow" href="#" disabled>В корзину</a>
```

P.S.

> Можно и button использовать.

В связке с `disabled` гораздо логичней. Но для элементов формы, лучше использовать метод `.prop()`

```
checkallow.prop('disabled', $(this).val() === '');
```

Comment: У меня в `a` ещё есть `onclick и data-...` Всё равно `button` использовать?

Comment: @steep, что использовать - вам видней, я могу только догадываться о ваших целях. А говорил я лишь о некой целесообразности использования тех или иных ресурсов.  Если речь идёт всё-таки о том, чтобы блокировать переход по ссылке до определенного момента и раз уж есть обработчик события, как вы заметили выше, то с его помощью и можно управлять "поведением" элемента. В частности, метод [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) или просто `return false;` в конце функции-обработчика